# How to manage online users in IM applications such as GTalk, Skype etc

Tags: java, database, xmpp, scalability, instant-messaging

Do they keep an online user list in a database and update it with every login and logout event, and run queries for online friends?

What about scalability?

Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to either store presence in a traditional database, or poll for changes to anything, you're going to have a tough time scaling your presence system.  Start with one of the open source [XMPP servers](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/), pull it apart, and see how it works.  Each one of them scales differently, but at least you'll understand more about where you need to start.